# Android: ProgressWheel o implementar otro Progress

Tags: android

Intento implementar un ProgressWheel pero no que esta quedando, espero y me puedan ayudar.

> MainActivity.java

```
else {
                progressWheel.setProgress(0.0f);

                progressWheel.setCallback(new ProgressWheel.ProgressCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressUpdate(float progress) {
                        if(progress == 0) {
                            progressWheel.setProgress(1.0f);
                        } else if(progress == 1.0f) {
                            progressWheel.setProgress(0.0f);
                        }
                        interpolatedValue.setText(String.format("%.2f", progress));
                    }
                });
                if (txtCode.getText().toString().trim().matches("[0-9]*")){//compruebo que los datos que se ingresaron son numeros
                    int inputData = Integer.parseInt(txtCode.getText().toString());//convierto lo que en el editText a int

                    int parameters[] = {inputData};
                    CheckIn checkIn = null;//hago una instancia de DataCheckIn y la guado en una variable
                    try {
                        checkIn = new SearchData().execute(parameters).get();//le paso el folio como parametro a SearchData
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                        if (checkIn != null && checkIn.getFolio() == inputData){
                            Intent intentIndex = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IndexActivity.class);//Creo un intent
                            startActivity(intentIndex);//inicio la actividad
                            finish();//se destruye la actividad
                        } else {
                            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("ERROR..").setMessage("El codigo no se encontro").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("ACEPTAR", null).show(); //mensaje si no existe el checkin
                            txtCode.setText("");
                        } //./else
                } else {
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("ERROR..").setMessage("El codigo no se encontro").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("ACEPTAR", null).show(); //mensaje si no existe el checkin
                    txtCode.setText("");
                } //./else
            } //./else*/
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
            android:id="@+id/progress_wheel"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            wheel:matProg_barColor="#5588FF"
            wheel:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true" />
```

La libreria que use es: [Material-ish Progress](https://github.com/pnikosis/materialish-progress)

Comment: Hola Elenasys, ya agregue el linc de la libreria que use.

Answer (score 0):

Para el `ProgressWheel`

```
    <com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
        android:id="@+id/progress_wheel"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinners"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        wheel:matProg_barColor="#5588FF"
        wheel:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true" />
```

no necesitas un callback!

Comenta esta parte:

```
/* progressWheel.setProgress(0.0f);

                progressWheel.setCallback(new ProgressWheel.ProgressCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressUpdate(float progress) {
                        if(progress == 0) {
                            progressWheel.setProgress(1.0f);
                        } else if(progress == 1.0f) {
                            progressWheel.setProgress(0.0f);
                        }
                        interpolatedValue.setText(String.format("%.2f", progress));
                    }
                }); */
```

Comment: Hola Elenasys, si queda pero lo que pasa es que se ejecuta al iniciar la aplicacion y lo que necesito es que cuando entre al primer else empiece a cargar, lo que pasa es que tarda un poquito en cargar las imagenes entonces quiero poner ese progress para que el usuario sepa que esta cargando la informacion. Gracias

Comment: probablemente pongas una imagen muy grande, y lo mas optimo sea achicarla y asi te evitas programar el progresswheel